# Simple 2D hair simulation/manipulation

Tags: physics, simulations, character

I would like to simulate *very* simple hair in a 2D environment, and will need to be able to "brush" the hair.

What I want to do:  A 2D character is facing squarely towards the player.  The player can then brush the character's hair.  Think of a little girl brushing her doll's hair into different styles.

In my preliminary Google searches, I found many 3D, super-optimized hair simulations for tens of thousands of hairs, which are far more complicated than I need.  I only need 100-500 hairs, and they only need to react to "brushing" by the player.

How might I do this?

Comment: I am tempted in giving an answer, but I'd like to request you to post either a small pic of that action (not animation, a paint.exe sketch should do), or a short description. The details required are: what is the view (front - i.e. back of the head pointing out of the screen or side - ears pointing out of the screen). One very simple thing to do even in 2D is implementing a follow the leader strategy. Here is the paper http://www.matthiasmueller.info/publications/FTLHairFur.pdf .

Comment: Thanks for the paper you linked to, I'll give it a read!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried it.

[image: Some hairstyles.]

Brown is **generated hair**. The red circle is the **hairbrush**. The hairstyles were achieved by brushing the hair with the hairbrush.

Here's how that works:

## The Hair

Hairs are like this:

- *Bendy*. Like a [bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). [Quadratic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves) ones are pretty simple.
- *Finite*. They start and end somewhere. They also have some fixed length.
- *Coloured*. They've got some [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) to them, usually pretty heavy in the R and G.
- (*Weighty*.) Let's ignore gravity to keep things simple -- and to allow awesome hairstyles.

This is roughly how you might translate that into a program:

```lua
oneHair = {
    start = vector(100,100),
    controlPoint = vector(120,70), -- For the bezier
    end = vector(100,200),
    length = 100,
    update = function(self)
        -- Make sure the END is within LENGTH of START
        -- (This isn't actually quite right, since beziers aren't lines,
        --  but it's a pretty good approximation...) 
    end,
    draw = function(self)
        -- Make a bezier curve using START, CONTROL and END.
        -- Sample it at intervals. Draw lines between samples.
    end
}
```

And then you just create really many. (There are 1200 in each of the pictures.)

It's useful to create them *on* or *within* some circle describing the shape of the head or the line of the fringe. (I used a filled half-circle for the bulk of the hair an edge of a different half-circle for the fringe.)

You can also vary the lengths of hairs. (I find bangs running down both sides of the face attractive, so I approximated hair length with [this quadratic function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%29%5E2) (picture just below), using the horizontal distance from the centre of the aforementioned guide circle as input.)

[image: graph of (x minus one) squared]

I recommend a similar approach, obviously keeping the desired style in mind.

## The Brush

The brushing mechanic is based on these (idealised) observations:

- Hair that touches the brush moves in the direction the brush is moved in, except slower.
- Brushing *along* hair straightens the hairs.
- Brushing *across* hair bends the hairs.

So my brushing code does essentially this:

1. Find hairs that touch brush (using their bezier curves)
2. For each hair:

   - Move the endpoint of the hair by some fraction of the pointer movement vector.
   - Project the movement vector of the pointer onto the perpendicular of the hair's direction. This gives a vector describing the brush motion in relation to the hair.
   - If the brush motion in relation to the hair is *more along than across* the hair, move the control point some fraction of the way toward the midpoint of the hair. This smooths the hair.
   - Else (if the brush motion is *more across than along*, move the control point some fraction of the pointer's movement vector.

## The Code

I made it with [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/) in [Lua](http://www.lua.org/). Here's my `main.lua`, if you just want to read:

```lua
local v = require "vector"
local graphics = love.graphics
local mouse = love.mouse
graphics.setBackgroundColor(255,255,255) --> white background

-- A function that makes bezier functions
-- Beziers have start point     p0
--              control point   p1
--              end point       p2
local function makeBezierFunction(p0,p1,p2)
    return function (t) 
        local pow = math.pow
        return pow( (1-t),2 ) * p0
               + 2 * (1-t) * t * p1
               + pow(t,2) * p2
    end 
end

-- Hair class
-- Encapsulates all that needs to be known to create, draw or update a hair.
local hair = {}
function hair.draw(self)
    -- Make a bezier function describing the shape of the hair
    local shape = makeBezierFunction(
        self.from,
        self.mid,
        self.to
    )
    -- This is the increment for one segment of a hair's bezier function
    local segIncr = 1/self.resolution
    for n=0,1-segIncr,segIncr do
        -- This and next sample point
        local x1,y1 = shape(n):unpack()
        local x2,y2 = shape(n + segIncr):unpack()

        graphics.setColor(unpack(self.col))
        graphics.line(x1,y1, x2,y2)
    end
end
function hair.update(self)

    -- Beziers can be longer than lines. This is an approximation to save us
    -- from some complicated maths.
    local vectorAlongLength = self.to - self.from
    -- Move endpoint to within the length of the hair of the start point.
    if vectorAlongLength:len() > self.length then
        self.to = self.from + vectorAlongLength:normalized() * self.length
    end

end
function hair.new(from, to, verticalBend, col) -- Create a new hair object
    return setmetatable({
        length = (from - to):len(),
        from = from,
        to   = to,
        mid  = from + v(0,verticalBend),
        verticalBend = verticalBend,
        resolution = 5,
        col = col,
    }, {
        __index = hair
    })
end
setmetatable(hair, {
    __call = function(_,...) return hair.new(...) end
})

local hairs = {}                -- all hairs stored here
local selectorSize = 30         -- radius of brush
local fringeOrigin = v(325,260) -- origin of the fringe guideline circle
local fringeRadius = 90         -- radius of the fringe guideline circle

-- Terrible drawing of a bald person, happy to soon receive lots of hair.
local portrait = graphics.newImage "portrait.png"

function love.load()

    ---[[ Bulk of hair, at the back
    local numHairs = 1000
    for _=1,numHairs do
        -- Get a random angle within 180 degrees
        local randomAngle = math.random() * math.pi + math.pi/2
        -- Find random point within circle (though offset somewhat)
        local point = fringeOrigin + v(0,-30) + v(math.sin(randomAngle), math.cos(randomAngle)) * (fringeRadius - 20 + math.random(50))
        -- Fairly dark brown
        local randomValue = math.random(50)
        local randomCol = {randomValue+50, randomValue+30, randomValue}
        local length = 30+math.random(50 * (math.pow(2*(point.x - fringeOrigin.x)/fringeRadius, 2)))
        local horizontalBend = -15 + math.random(30)
        local verticalBend = math.random(length)
        local newHair = hair(v(point.x, point.y), v(point.x+horizontalBend, point.y+length), verticalBend, randomCol)
        table.insert(hairs, newHair)
    end
    --]]
    ---[[ Fringe
    local numHairs = 200
    -- get random points on fringe circle arc
    for _=1,numHairs do
        -- Get a random angle within 180 degrees
        local randomAngle = math.random() * math.pi + math.pi/2
        -- Find random point somewhere ON (NOT WITHIN) the fringe arc
        local point = fringeOrigin + v(math.sin(randomAngle), math.cos(randomAngle)) * fringeRadius
        local randomValue = math.random(100)
        local randomCol = {randomValue+50, randomValue+30, randomValue}
        local length = 50+math.random(50 * (math.pow(2*(point.x - fringeOrigin.x)/fringeRadius, 2)))
        local horizontalBend = -15 + math.random(30)
        local verticalBend = math.random(length)
        local newHair = hair(v(point.x, point.y), v(point.x+horizontalBend, point.y+length), verticalBend, randomCol)
        table.insert(hairs, newHair)
    end
    --]]
end

lastMousePos = v()
mousePos = v()
mouseMovement = v() -- Movement vector of the mouse this step
function love.update()

    mousePos = v(mouse.getPosition())
    mouseMovement = mousePos - lastMousePos

    if mouse.isDown "l" then -- Left mouse button pressed

        -- Find all hairs with ends nearby the cursor
        local nearbyHairs = {}
        for _,hair in ipairs(hairs) do
            -- Create a function describing the shape of the bezier
            local shape = makeBezierFunction(
                hair.from,
                hair.from + v(0,hair.verticalBend),
                hair.to
            )   
            -- This is the increment for one segment of a hair's bezier function
            local segIncr = 1/hair.resolution
            for n=0,1,segIncr do
                local pointOnShape = v(shape(n):unpack())
                -- If it's close enough to the mouse
                if (pointOnShape - mousePos):len() < selectorSize then
                    -- Select it
                    table.insert(nearbyHairs, hair)
                end
            end 

        end

        -- Apply transforms to each hair
        for _,hair in ipairs(nearbyHairs) do

            -- Move endpoint along with movement vector
            hair.to = hair.to + 0.5 * mouseMovement

            -- Find movement in relation to hair
            local movementAcross = mouseMovement:projectOn((hair.to - hair.from):perpendicular())

            -- If the movement was ALONG the hair
            if math.abs(movementAcross.x) < 10 then
                -- Smooth the hair by moving control point closer to midpoint
                local midPoint = (hair.to + hair.from) /2
                hair.mid = 0.85 * hair.mid + midPoint * 0.15
            else -- Movement was ACROSS the hair
                -- Move the control point along with the movement vector
                hair.mid.x = hair.mid.x + 0.25 * mouseMovement.x
            end
        end

    end

    -- Update hairs to make sure their lengths stay the same
    for _,hair in ipairs(hairs) do hair:update() end

    lastMousePos = mousePos
end

function love.draw(dt)
    -- Draw the bald portrait image
    graphics.draw(portrait, 200, 100)
    -- This is a nice cheat for making less hair look like it has more volume
    graphics.setLineWidth(2)

    for _,hair in ipairs(hairs) do
        hair:draw(dt)
    end

    -- Draw brush pointer
    graphics.setColor(255,0,0)
    graphics.circle("line", mousePos.x, mousePos.y, selectorSize)

    -- The fringe line
    --graphics.arc("line", fringeOrigin.x, fringeOrigin.y, fringeRadius, -math.pi, 0)
end
```

If you want to have a play with it, [get LÖVE](https://love2d.org/) (any OS is OK) and open [my love file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/196227/hairbrushing.love) with it.

If you want to see the source code in its entirety, just change the `.love` extension to `.zip` and unpack.

Comment: Well done, impressive!

Comment: Wow!  This is very in depth.  Thanks so much, I hope you had as much fun writing it as I'm expecting to have messing with it!  You rock!

Comment: @lon Heh, *messing with it*. :> Tell me if you find unclear parts or if you make awesome things with it!